# What protects the access to the Twitter API?

Tags: authentication, twitter

I get a consumer key and secret and a token with a token secret to send with my request to the API.

Why is this secure? Couldn't someone intercept the keys and than use them themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `https://api.twitter.com/` it is the `https` that protects the API keys with *Transport Layer Security* (TLS).